# How do I set a conditional on Paginated pages?

Tags: conditionals, navigation

I am trying to set a conditional on a navigation element using segmentation, and this works fine except when I hit the pagination stuff.

The pagination is in increments of 50 so I tried the following but it only works if the page is P50.

```
<ul>
<li><a {if segment_2 == "" OR segment_2 == "article" AND segment_2 >="P50"}class="active"{/if} href="{site_url}news/">Clean Energy News</a></li>
<li><a {if segment_2 == "releases"}class="active"{/if} href="{site_url}news/releases">News Releases</a></li>
<li><a {if segment_2 == "multimedia"}class="active"{/if}{if segment_2 == "photos"}class="active"{/if} href="{site_url}news/multimedia">Multimedia</a></li>
<li><a {if segment_2 == "archive"}class="active"{/if}href="{site_url}news/archive">News Archive</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a conditional I can put on segment_2 that will work? Note that I have other nav elements that I don't want it to interfere with. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [**MD Detect Page Type**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/md-detect-page-type) or [**Switchee**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) addons.

Answer (score 1):

For navigation, whether I am using an embed method or the [template partials](http://eeinsider.com/articles/template-partials-using-stash/) with [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) approach, I find it easier to pass a parameter specifying which section I want active rather than trying to detect it manually.

In my experience there is always an edge case requiring a more manual / granular approach that will defeat any automatic setup down the road.

**Embeds**

In main template

```
{embed="embeds/.header" active_nav="articles"}
```

In embedded template

```
<ul>
    <li><a{if embed:active_nav == "articles"} class="active"{/if} href="{site_url}articles/">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a{if embed:active_nav == "news"} class="active"{/if} href="{site_url}news/">News</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**template partials**

In partial template

```
{embed="layouts/.main"}
{exp:stash:set_value name="active_nav" value="articles"}
```

In layout (.main) template

```
<ul>
    <li><a{if "{exp:stash:get name='active_nav'}" == "articles"} class="active"{/if} href="{site_url}articles/">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a{if "{exp:stash:get name='active_nav'}" == "news"} class="active"{/if} href="{site_url}news/">News</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**Variant with body class only**

In partial template

```
{embed="layouts/.main"}
{exp:stash:set_value name="body_class" value="body_articles"}
```

In layout template

```
<body{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="body_class"}} class="{exp:stash:get name='body_class'}"{/if}>

<ul>
    <li class="articles"><a href="{site_url}articles/">Articles</a></li>
    <li class="news"><a href="{site_url}news/">News</a></li>
...
</ul>
```

in your CSS

```
.body_articles .articles > a
{
    do something
}
```

From the two add-ons mentioned by Anna, I would go down the switchee route

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}

    {case value="#^P(\\d+)$#|''"}
        code if pagination page
    {/case}

    {case default="Yes"}
        code if not a pagination page
    {/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

The advantage of switchee beeing that, if you have channel entries loops or anything heavy process-wise, it only get executed should the tested condition apply. Better for performance.

Comment: No problem. Hope it will help fmz too. Using such a method for navigation instead of a more automated solution really saved my bacon on some occasions